Pytest fixture not running x times with given parameters
I have the following pytest fixture (that also uses other fixtures as parameters) that uses a dynamodb client to put Order items:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def function_order(request, dynamodb_client, cleanup_orders):
    delivery_date = "01-01-2022"
    if hasattr(request, "param"):
        delivery_date = request.param.get("delivery_date")

    order_id = f"ORDER-{str(uuid.uuid4())}"

    records = [
        {
            "order_id": {"S": order_id},
            "delivery_date": {"S": delivery_date},
        }
    ]

    for record in records:
        dynamodb_client.put_item(
            TableName="orders",
            Item=record,
        )

    cleanup_orders.append(order_id)

    return {"order_id": order_id, "records": records}

I also have an integration test defined that defines parameters to send to my fixture: function_order. This endpoint should return a 400 when hitting my post order endpoint. It should return a 400 in the event that there is an attempt to post a third order for a specified delivery date. In other words, if I already have two orders posted with a delivery date of 12-12-2024, a third attempt to post an order to this date should be a bad request.
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "function_order",
    [
        {"delivery_date": "12-12-2024"},
        {"delivery_date": "12-12-2024"},
    ],
    indirect=True,
)
def test_post_v1_orders_exceeds_order_limit_returns_400(
    request_helper, function_order
):
    delivery_date = "12-12-2024"
    response = request_helper.post(
        "/v1/orders",
        body=order.order_record(delivery_date=delivery_date),
    )
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert (
        response.json().get("error")
        == f"Order limit exceeded for date: {delivery_date}. Max orders: 2"
    )

The problem is that the function_order fixture is only being executed once when the same delivery date is used as a parameter twice. However, if I specify a different delivery date as a parameter, it executes twice as expected. Why is this happening and how can I get my fixture to execute twice even if the same parameters are used in both calls?

So I found a solution that worked for my case. Changing my order_function fixture to return an internal function allowed me to pass args to the fixture from my test case.
My updated fixture:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def function_order(request, dynamodb_client, cleanup_orders):
    def _get_order_record(delivery_date="01-01-2022"):
        order_id = f"ORDER-{str(uuid.uuid4())}"

        records = [
            {
                "order_id": {"S": order_id},
                "delivery_date": {"S": delivery_date},
            }
        ]

        for record in records:
            dynamodb_client.put_item(
                TableName="orders",
                Item=record,
            )

        cleanup_orders.append(order_id)

        return {"order_id": order_id, "records": records}

    return _get_order_record

Updated test case:

def test_post_v1_orders_exceeds_order_limit_returns_400(request_helper, function_order):
    delivery_date = "12-12-2024"

    function_order(delivery_date)
    function_order(delivery_date)

    response = request_helper.post(
        "/v1/orders",
        body=order.order_record(delivery_date=delivery_date),
    )
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert (
        response.json().get("error")
        == f"Order limit exceeded for date: {delivery_date}. Max orders: 2"
    )

